# How to set each keyboard layout to its very own shortcut combination (imitate Windows functional)?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

On Windows I always had the possibility to set each keyboard layout to some global hotkey (look at the picture).
For example, due to multilanguage scope of work, I need 5 keyboard layouts - so in Windows I can just give to each one of them its own keyboard key combination like **Ctrl + Shift + 2**, **Ctrl + Shift + 5** and so on

In Ubuntu you can change the hotkey for **keyboard layout switching** to almost any option you want - but **only for switching from previous to next** and not to **direct switch on**.

So if you have 3 or 5 or more layouts - you need to spare tons of time for switching processes: you need to revolve your layouts by hotkey forward or backward or use mouse and layout menu - which is very uncomfortable and need your time and attention to control what exactly keyboard layout you are having right now.

So maybe somebody know - how in Ubuntu to do the custom global hotkey for direct switch on to the very one certain keyboard layout?

I just want to have possibility to press **Ctrl + Shift + 3** and be sure - now I have egnlish keyboard layout and the same behaviour with other languages/layouts.

[image]

Comment: You will need to give details on your current system and desktop environment because options, if any, can depend on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a script.

- Save the below script as `$HOME/bin/mylayouts`
- Make it executable:

  ```
  chmod +x $HOME/bin/mylayouts
  ```
- Relogin

Now you can switch layout by running for instance

```
mylayouts us
mylayouts ro_std
```

And that in turn allows you to create custom shortcuts for the purpose.

This is the example script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

# layouts
us="('xkb', 'us')"
ro_std="('xkb', 'ro+std')"
latam="('xkb', 'latam')"
es="('xkb', 'es')"

case $1 in
  us)     NEW=us
    ;;
  ro_std) NEW=ro_std
    ;;
  latam)  NEW=latam
    ;;
  es)     NEW=es
    ;;
  *)      echo "Invalid argument"
          exit 1
    ;;
esac

NEWLIST="[${!NEW}"
for L in 'us' 'ro_std' 'latam' 'es'; do
    if [ "$L" = "$NEW" ]; then
        continue
    else
        NEWLIST="$NEWLIST, ${!L}"
    fi
done
NEWLIST="$NEWLIST]"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[${!NEW}]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "$NEWLIST"
```

If you adapt the script to your needs, you can now from Ubuntu Settings
create custom shortcut like:
name: **us_colemak**
command: **mylayouts.sh us_colemak**
shortcut: **Ctrl + Shift + 5**

*Caveat:*

Using numerical keys as part of the shortcut is a bit tricky. If you for instance use the English (US) layout when creating a shortcut by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, the shortcut actually created is **Ctrl + Shift + @** (since <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> results in the **@** character with the English (US) layout). Then, if you for instance are on a latin layout, where <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> results in the **"** character, the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> won't give you the expected result.

Probably it's less error prone to use letters instead of numbers.

In any case, this answer is not a perfect solution. There is apparently room for improvement.

Comment: thanks, it works! p.s: I added the shortcut example in your answer, hope, you don't mind

Comment: @GreenJoffer: Well, your proposed edit was not consistent with some parts of the answer, so I modified it.

Comment: you are right, that's why when I was setting the shortcuts - I was checking before setting that current layout is **default 'us'**. I added 4 layouts, all works, but somehow, don't know why, the shortcut **Ctrl + Shift + 4** just does not work, so I used the next number (maybe bug or reserved for some system needings)